# How to handle index out of range

Tags: python, list, error-handling, a-star

Im building an A star algorithm and i want to store the 8 possible directions to move to in a dictionary like so: ["NW: *a location north west, which i call from a 2D list which stores all units on my map*]

For the North west example, i would call the unit like so:

```
["NW": map[p.x -1][p.y-1]]
```

which stores the top left (or NW) unit (p is the starting location unit, from which i call its x and y coordinate. map is what I'm using to illustrate my 2D list which holds all the units on my grid). 
I have to do a similar thing for all 8 directions around a starting unit.
The issue is that the starting unit could at any point be on the edge of the map, so if i try to go NW,W, or SW when the start node is at the left border of my map, ill obviously get an index out of bounds error of some sort.

how can i efficiently test for all the 8 cases at once? i don't want to add them all to my dictionary individually and surround them each with their own try statement. In essence i want to add this piece of code into my program:

```
dic = ["NW": map[p.x -1][p.y-1], "N": map[p.x][p.y-1], "NE" map[p.x 
+1][p.y-1], ...]
```

and so on, for all 8 directions.

Comment: `[p for p in dic if isValidPosition(p)]`?

Comment: where would i put that line exactly? and is `isValidPosition` a built in function in Python? what exactly does it check for?

Comment: No, it's something you'd write to validate that a position isn't out-of-range.  If you don't understand how list comprehensions work, please read up on that first.

Comment: Ill read up on list comprehension thanks. I don't understand how id write the method isValidPosition, wouldn't i have to check all 8 cases there anyway?

Comment: it's generally faster and easier to pad the outside of your map with obstacles. this way you don't need an extra statement

Comment: the issue with that is that i need to be able to take _any_ grid arrangement as a file, so i can't assume the borders will be obstacles.